# Naivgate into nested structures with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have an understanding issue regarding a programming technique: using pointer to navigate into nested structures.

what I have (pseudo code):

```
typedef struct lookup_descriptor_s {
  uint8_t LookupData[9];          
  unsigned LookupDataSize: 1;  
} lookup_descriptor_t;

typedef struct descriptor_s {     
  lookup_descriptor_t *IdLookupList;     
  device_descriptor_t *DeviceList;     
  usage_descriptor_t *UsageList;     
  uint32_t *member;     
  uint32_t member2; 
} descriptor_t;

typedef struct rf_mac_setup_s {
...some_members     
  struct descriptor_s *description_table;     
  int foo;     
  char foo2;     
etc... 
} rf_mac_setup_t;
```

Here is the executed code :

```c
  descriptor_t *p;
  rf_mac_setup *rf_mac;
  p = rf_mac->description_table;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < some_size; i++) {
    if (some_function(p)) {
       return p;
    }
    p++;
  }
```

My question is : when p is incremented the first time, at which member does it point? Does it point to  `rf_mac_setup->foo` or `p->DeviceList`, or even `p->IdLookupList->LookupDataSize`? How does this pointer will step forward with each incrementation? (okay, that's two questions). I am a little bit confused here on how this pointer will allow me to navigate into these structures. Note that I am programming with a specific board and I can't launch debug session (unfortunately!).

I tried to read the memory, but I fail in hard fault handlers. I tried to search, but the topics I found weren't answering my problem.

Comment: *at which member does it point?* Why would it point at any member of that struct? Where does `rf_mac->description_table` point to before you enter the loop? You should show real code instead of pseudo code. How can we know whether you initialize `rf_mac` at all and how?

Comment: Hello, thank you for editing my code body ;). Actually, rf_mac_setup is a parameter of the function in which this code appears. rf_mac_setup *rf_mac; line doesn't exist in the actual code, but it would take a looooot of time to tell you where it point, because I am working with a big rf stack, and rf_mac is a very big structure modified all along the code. With a very simple structure, let us say with 3 int members, p would point to the first member, then the second, etc.. because when the code compiles, it writes the whole structure successively in the memory, am I right?

Comment: Why would `p` point to any member? It points to an object of type `descriptor`, that is to the address of first element. If you increment `p` then it points to the next object, still of type `descriptor`. That is the address after that whole struct, (again first member of that struct), not some member in the middle of the struct.

Comment: Hi Eric Postpischil, you're right, my bad, I edited the code, sorry for giving confusing pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   descriptor *p;
>   rf_mac_setup *rf_mac;
>   p = rf_mac->description_table;
>   for (uint8_t i = 0; i < some_size; i++) {
>     if (some_function(p)) {
>        return p;
>     }
>     p++;
>   }
> ```
>
> My question is : when p is incremented the first time, at which member does it point?

There is no reason to think that `p` ever points to *any* member of `*rf_mac`.  It is initially set equal to `rf_mac->description_table`, with the result that the two pointers point to the same object (supposing that the pointer is valid).  But it is the pointer `rf_mac->description_table` itself that is the member, not whatever object it points to at any given time.

When you increment `p`, it points to the next element of the array of `struct descriptor_s` in which the previously pointed-to object resides, or immediately past the end of that array, where an object that is not part of a declared array is treated as an array of length 1.  That will not be any of the structure members that have been shown.

**Addendum**: Since it seems not to be clear: there is no C operator that provides for iterating over the members of a structure, neither by use of a pointer nor by any other means.  You can use a pointer to iterate over elements of an array, but that's an altogether different  thing.

Comment: Hello, Eric Postpischil yes, p is actually descriptor_t *, my bad, I edited the code.